# If $T^rv=v$, are $v,Tv,\ldots,T^{r-1}v$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, symmetry, linear-independence

Let $V$ be  a finite-dimensional vector space over the field of **complex numbers**, and let $T:V \to V$ be a linear map.

Suppose that we have a nonzero vector $v \in V$ such that $T^rv=v$, and that $r$ is minimal, i.e. $T^kv \neq v$ for $0<k<r$.

Are $v,Tv,\ldots,T^{r-1}v$ linearly independent?

I tried to assume dependence and apply various powers of $T$, but so far came up with nothing...

Comment: This fails already for $r=2$ and $T(v)=-v$. You can generalize for any $r$ by setting $T(v)=\epsilon v$ where $\epsilon$ is a primitive $r$th root of unity in $\mathbb C$,

Comment: You need also to assume that $T^{j}v\neq T^{k}v$, $j\neq k$, $1\leq j,l< r$

Comment: $T=\left(\begin{array}{ll}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right), v=\left(\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 1\end{array}\right)$ seems also a counterexample (Here $r=4$)

Comment: @onriv Thanks, that is a nice and interesting example; it is less trivial since $T$ doesn't act on $v$ by scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not true. Suppose $Tv=-v$ with $v \neq 0$. Then $T^{2}v=v$ and $Tv \neq v$. But $v,Tv$ are not independent.